# Do subshells started by () read startup files?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Parentheses are used in shell to group commands, executing them in a subshell, so that they don't affect parent shell environment.

Now, I wonder if this spawned subshells do read init files, like any other shells.
From direct experience I'd say they don't.
But I don't find any place where that is stated.

Also, is this different for different types of shells?

Comment: `man bash` and `man zsh` (not sure about that one, since I don't use it). For example, bash documents that it reads startup files when it's invoked as a login shell.

Comment: I'm afraid the situation is more complex than that. Not only login shells read startup files. There are startup files for all shells, for login shells, for interactive shells, both in bash and zsh. What a shell reads is actually a combination of those files depending on their characteristics, and how startup files are linked (frequently they `source` each other at some circumstances). What I want to know is if () subshells are hardwired not to behave as normal shells when starting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the behaviour of shells is not particularly well-defined since the [only applicable standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_title.html) was essentially the result of reverse-engineering the behaviour of various commonly-used shells. Nonetheless, there is an expectation that shells will converge to the standard, albeit with extensions.

Having said that, here's what Posix says about [`(...)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_01):

> `(compound-list)`
>           Execute compound-list in a subshell environment.

And a [subshell environment](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12):

> A subshell environment shall be created as a duplicate of the shell environment, except that signal traps that are not being ignored shall be set to the default action. Changes made to the subshell environment shall not affect the shell environment. Command substitution, commands that are grouped with parentheses, and asynchronous lists shall be executed in a subshell environment. Additionally, each command of a multi-command pipeline is in a subshell environment; as an extension, however, any or all commands in a pipeline may be executed in the current environment. All other commands shall be executed in the current shell environment.

The take-away here is that the subshell environment is a "duplicate of the shell environment", and not a new shell; the only difference is the specific exception for signal traps. So it is pretty clearly not expected that the subshell will undergo reinitialization, such as rereading startup files.

Posix only provides one requirement for start-up files, which is documented in Section 4 in the description of the [`sh` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html):

> ENV
>
> > This variable, when and only when an interactive shell is invoked, shall be subjected to parameter expansion by the shell, and the resulting value shall be used as a pathname of a file containing shell commands to execute in the current environment.

Most shells implement a richer set of start-up files with specific names, so that the `ENV` variable may not be necessary. So the fact that Posix states "when and **only when** an interactive shell is invoked" is only indicative, but I think it is a good indication.

Answer (score 1):

When a subshell is started, it is just a child resulting from a `fork()`, thus it inherits all from the father and doesn't need to read the config files, whose it already knows.

Conversely, when a shell is `exec()`-uted, it looses everything except PIDs and redirections, thus it has to read again config files.

Comment: Why everything has to be lost? Is not normal unix environment inheritance in place? If startup files don't clobber environment defining it anew, I don't see why they can't inherit variables from their parent. In fact, I have my startup files defined that way, for non-login shells, and they normally inherit parent's environment.

Comment: Is that behaviour (subshells just forking and not executing) documented anywhere? To read more about that. Thx.

Comment: Subshells are forked childs by definition.

Comment: Well, that's my problem. I don't find where *the* definition of subshell is. Voting up your answer anyway.

Comment: You won't find an actual definition of a subshell in `man bash`; here is a definition in [the absg](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html).

Comment: I had seen that definition, but it is very vague/unclear to me. It seems to consider a subshell *every* child process, not only child shell processes. Also, it says nothing about forking but not exec'ing. Note that I think it's probably true (makes sense and would explain not reading init files). I'd just like to see it written somewhere. If noboy is able to provide that, I'll accept this answer. Thx.